# Get Path Param with HTML + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, path-parameter

I have a simple static HTML that prints the value of the param in queryString:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        document.write(urlParams.get('param'));
    </script>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

http://static-page.com?param=valueParam Prints: "valueParam"

**Question:** There is a way to do the same with static html and path param?

Like: http://static-page.com/valueParam

Comment: `window.location.pathname`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković When I try the link http://static-page.com/valueParam the result is 404 not found

Comment: That really depends on the server config where the `static-page` is hosted...

Comment: Do you have a sample of that configuration? My page is hosted on Vercel